# JS/jQuery number increasing animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Let's say i have a div called `.number` containing a number.

i want to increase that number to a new one dynamically with a counter increasing effect like this [one](http://chartbeat.com/) in the bottom.

Any lightweight solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Where's the number coming from, and in what way is it 'dynamic'?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  var ele = $('#haha');
  var clr = null;
  var rand = (Math.random() * 100000) >> 0;
  (loop = function() {
    clearTimeout(clr);
    (inloop = function() {
      ele.html(rand+=1);
      if(!(rand % 50)) {
        return;
      }
      clr = setTimeout(inloop, 30);
    })(); 
    setTimeout(loop, 2500);
  })();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/obysrnm2/)

**Edit**  :

```
$(function () {
    var ele = $('#haha');
    var clr = null;
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000); // just a random number(initial number)
    loop();
    function loop() {
        clearTimeout(clr);
        inloop();
        setTimeout(loop, 2500); //call 'loop()' after 2.5 seconds
    }
    function inloop() {
        ele.html(rand += 1);
        if (!(rand % 50)) {
            return;
        }
        clr = setTimeout(inloop, 30); //call 'inloop()' after 30 milliseconds
    }
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  var ele = $('#haha');
  var clr = null;
  var rand = (Math.random() * 100000) >> 0;
  (loop = function() {
    clearTimeout(clr);
    (inloop = function() {
      ele.html(rand += 1);
      if (!(rand % 50)) {
        return;
      }
      clr = setTimeout(inloop, 30);
    })();
    setTimeout(loop, 2500);
  })();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="haha"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! the prob is that i can't understand this coz you used a lot of in functions and classes, can you please make it easier?

Comment: In the second example, you need to change `clearInterval()` to `clearTimeout()` as `clearTimeout()` is what is supposed to be used with `setTimeout()`.